# Embed an svg file in svg document, access it's objects via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

I am looking for a way how to load the svg content from external file, in a placeholder element, and when it's loaded, access it's objects for manipulation/modifictation.

Something like this:

```
Host file:

<body>
<svg width="700" height="500">
  <rect x="10" y="10" height="480" width="680" fill="red"/>
  <g id="placeholder"></g>
</svg>
</body>

drawing.svg file:

<svg>
  <circle id="obj1" cx="300" y="250" r="100" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

And here's some pseudo-code:

```
var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");
loadSVGFile("drawing.svg", placeholder, function(svg) {
  // Callback called when the file has loaded
  var obj = svg.document.getElementById("obj1");
  obj.setAttribute("fill", "black");
});
```

Currently I am creating in memory a new `<object>` element, load the svg file, hook up an onload event handler that copies the document content to the target placeholder element with recursive node crawler. Not pretty, but it works. I am hoping there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work.  I haven't properly tested it.  But it is a cut-down version of some other code, so it should at least be very close.

```js
function loadSVGFile(svgURL, placeholderElem, callbackFn) {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
       var svg = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
       placeholderElem.parentElement.replaceChild(svg, placeholderElem); // Replace the placeholder node
       //targetNode.appendChild(svg); // Insert into the placeholder node 
       if (callbackFn) {
         callbackFn(svg);
       }
     }
   }
   xhr.open('GET', svgURL, true);
   xhr.send(null);
}            

var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

loadSVGFile("drawing.svg", placeholder, function(svg) {
  // Callback called when the file has loaded
  var obj = svg.ownerDocument.getElementById("obj1");
  obj.setAttribute("fill", "black");
});
```

```html
<body>
<svg width="700" height="500">
  <rect x="10" y="10" height="480" width="680" fill="red"/>
  <g id="placeholder"></g>
</svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested the code, and fixed few bugs there. The most important fix was that the svg variable is a node object and it does not have a document property. We have to use ownerDocument property instead.